org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions @XmlValue
org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions. Si une classe comporte la propriété @XmlElement, elle ne peut pas comporter la propriété @XmlValue.
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Objectif {
    
     @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id; 
    
        //@XmlValue à corriger
        @Column(name = "value")
        @XmlValue
        private String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "statut", required = true)
    @Column(name = "statut")
    private String statut;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "cv24_id")
       private CV24 cv24;

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
     
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the statut
     */
    public String getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    /**
     * @param statut the statut to set
     */
    public void setStatut(String statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    
}

Lorsque j'assais de faire des insertions dans ma base de données, j'obtiens l'erreur signifiée en entête du proble.
Voici les flux xml que je veux réaliser
<objectif statut="Stage">Dev</objectif>

I think you should add the @XmlTransient to any fields that are not needed in your XML representation (such as id and cv24 fields).
By default, using @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) will make :

Every non static, non transient field in a Jakarta XML Binding-bound class will be automatically bound to XML, unless annotated by XmlTransient. Getter/setter pairs are bound to XML only when they are explicitly annotated by some of the Jakarta XML Binding annotations.

